# May I control the turtlesim by sending commands to turtlesim/Pose?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS, using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. After coding the basic tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29, I am trying to control the turtle by sending the commands to turtlesim/Pose.

I program the code, CMakeLists.txt, and package.xml properly, and the catkin_make works properly. However, the turtle does not move, and there is no link between /publish_pose node (my publishing node) and /turtlesim node by executing rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph as follows.

[image: image description]

My code of the publishing node is listed below.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>  // For geometry_msgs::Twist
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h> // rostopic type /turtle1/pose
#include <stdlib.h> // For rand() and RAND_MAX

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Initialize the ROS system and become a node.
  ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_pose");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a publisher object.
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<turtlesim::Pose>(
    "/turtle1/pose", 1000);

  // Seed the random number generator.
  srand(time(0));

  // Loop at 2Hz until the node is shut down.
  ros::Rate rate(2);
  while(ros::ok()) {
    // Create and fill in the message.  The other four
    // fields, which are ignored by turtlesim, default to 0.
    turtlesim::Pose msg;
    msg.x = float(rand())/float(RAND_MAX);
    msg.y = float(rand())/float(RAND_MAX);
    msg.theta = 2*float(rand())/float(RAND_MAX) - 1;

    // Publish the message.
    pub.publish(msg);

    // Send a message to rosout with the details.
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random pose command:"<<" x=" << msg.x<<" y=" << msg.y<<" theta=" << msg.theta);

    // Wait until it's time for another iteration.
    rate.sleep();
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220266/may-i-control-the-turtlesim-by-sending-commands-to-turtlesim/pose?/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: no you cannot not (at least not using that topic).

---

Longer: as you can see on [wiki/turtlesim - Nodes - turtlesim_node - Subscribed Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim#Subscribed_Topics), the `turtleX/pose` topic is only *published* to by the `turtlesim_node` node, so no incoming messages will be expected there (it is only an output). The only subscription is a `turtleX/cmd_vel` ([geometry_msgs/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html)) topic, which is the only way to make the turtle move in the normal manner.

To place the turtle at a certain position without it having to travel there, you should use the `turtleX/teleport_*` services.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2015-11-02**:
thx. will try that.